# WebForms GridView inserting URL into the row

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

My code

```
<Columns>
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText ="File Name" DataTextField="FileName"
 SortExpression="FileName" DataNavigateUrlFields="FileNameAndPath"
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="filesUploadedTh" >
</Columns>
```

`FileName` = Just a file name without full path.
`FileNameAndPath` = Full address of the file.

`GridView` has

```
DataKeyNames="FileNameAndPath"
```

The result that I'm getting is:

```
<a>FileName</a>
```

My problem is that for some reason href tag with URL in it is not being generated.

Comment: Are you sure the property `FileNameAndPath` has value? It won't generate the href if it is empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

"DataNavigateUrlFields" auto inserts http://domain.name/....

My "FileNameAndPath" already has that so "DataNavigateUrlFields" did not like that and that is why was not inserting anything.

I removed "http://domain.name/" from "FileNameAndPath" and it started working!